# How to store things in asyncstorage?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm having some problems setting up asyncstorage. example: if the user has switch to darkmode, darkmode should still be enabled when the user start the app again.

I'm also unsure if this is the right way of doing this.

any help is appreciated.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

toggle.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Switch } from "react-native";
import { useTheme } from "../Data/ThemeContext";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export const Toggle = () => {
  const { colors, setScheme, isDark } = useTheme();

  const toggleScheme = () => {
    isDark ? setScheme("light") : setScheme("dark");
    setScheme(isDark);
    storeSetScheme(isDark);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    restoreDarkModeAsync();
  }, []);

  const asyncStorageKey = "@key";

  const storeSetScheme = (isDark) => {
    const stringifiedIsDark = JSON.stringify(isDark);

    AsyncStorage.setItem(asyncStorageKey, stringifiedIsDark).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

  const restoreDarkModeAsync = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(asyncStorageKey)
      .then((stringifiedIsDark) => {
        const parsedTodos = JSON.parse(stringifiedIsDark);

        if (!parsedTodos || typeof parsedTodos !== "object") return;

        setScheme(parsedTodos);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Switch
      value={isDark}
      onValueChange={toggleScheme}
      thumbColor={colors.text}
      trackColor={{ true: colors.text, false: colors.text }}
    />
  );
};
```

ThemeContext.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native-appearance";
import { lightColors, darkColors } from "../Theme/colorThemes";

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  isDark: false,
  colors: lightColors,
  setScheme: () => {},
});

export const ThemeProvider = (props) => {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  const [isDark, setIsDark] = React.useState(colorScheme === "dark");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsDark(colorScheme === "dark");
  }, [colorScheme]);

  const defaultTheme = {
    isDark,

    colors: isDark ? darkColors : lightColors,

    setScheme: (scheme) => setIsDark(scheme === "dark"),
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={defaultTheme}>
      {props.children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTheme = () => React.useContext(ThemeContext);
```

Comment: AsyncStorage keeps the data only if you don't remove or uninstall the app. So they way you are using it works. But your code looks like following a weird flow. The toggleScheme function you are setting up an String but then you are passing a boolean. Check well the flow.

Comment: @DiegoMolina would you mind helping me with the code cuz im out of ideas, the thing is the Switch doesnt move now when i have the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useColorScheme()` returns `string` or `null`. But you have next check in `restoreDarkModeAsync`

```
if (!parsedTodos || typeof parsedTodos !== "object") return;
```

that's why it fails.

And here is more correct and clean way to toggle scheme

```
const toggleScheme = () => {
    const nextScheme = isDark ? "light" : "dark";
    setScheme(nextScheme);
    storeSetScheme(nextScheme);
};
```